# How to randomly select item from list that's at least n spaces away from another item?

Tags: javascript, list

I have a long list of items in JavaScript, something like this:

```js
list = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]];
```

I want to randomly select one inner bracket of items e.g. [1,2,3] and another that is **at least** two elements away from it, e.g. [3,4,5] or [4,5,6]. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a `getDistantIndex` function that tries random indexes until it finds one that meets the specified miniumum distance from our first random index.

(The downside of this approach is that the work is repeated until the condition is met, but for a quick task like this, the processor won't get too mad at us.)

The function is generalized to work with any array, not just your particular matrix of integers.

```js
const getRandomIndex = (arr) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

const getFirstIndex = (arr) =>
  getRandomIndex(arr);

const getDistantIndex = (arr, firstInd, minDistance) => {
  do{ distantInd = getRandomIndex(arr); }
  while(Math.abs(firstInd - distantInd) < minDistance);
  return distantInd;
}


const
  list = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6]],
  minimumDistance = 2,
  firstIndex = getFirstIndex(list),

  firstSelection =  list[firstIndex],
  secondSelection = list[getDistantIndex(list, firstIndex, 2)];


console.log(firstSelection);
console.log(secondSelection);
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I wanted to choose two elements that are at least 2 spaces apart?

Answer (score 2):

Without writing code, for a list of n items, select a random number between 1 and n inclusive. Create a new list of integers 1 to n, deleting the random number and the one or two nearest neighbors. Then randomly select one of the elements in the remaining list.